# DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line in procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, procedure

I have many `DBMS_OUTPUT.put_line` in a `procedure`, but when I launch it I only have this message in the SQL Developer console :

> anonymous block completed

This is how I launch my procedure :

```
BEGIN
  MY_PROCEDURE();
  commit;
END;
```

How to fix that ?

Comment: @Allan Indeed, the `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON` was missing. It works. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I forgot `SET SERVEROUTPUT ON`...

It works :

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON;
BEGIN
  MY_PROCEDURE();
  commit; 
END;
```

Comment: you can also open the DBMS_OUTPUT panel under the View menu and enable polling for your connections